# Aura Record Data component: some fields can't be updated

Tags: aura, force-recorddata

We have been using this code for several years without issue however we have suddenly come across an issue this week. Here is the code:

```
<aura:attribute name="objectFields"
                type="Object"
                access="private"
                description="Used to reference a record fields in component markup."/>
<force:recordData aura:id="fieldUpdate"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.objectFields}"
                      targetError="{!v.fieldUpdateError}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}"
                      mode="EDIT"/>
```

In the Javascript I have tested many fields, some are updateable and some aren't. What is causing the ones to not be updateable?

Here is a sample of what I have found:

`component.set('v.objectFields.Min_Decision_Days__c', 123)` - undefined

`component.get('v.objectFields.Min_Decision_Days__c')` - undefined

`component.set('v.objectFields.Geolocation__Latitude__s', 51)` - undefined

`component.get('v.objectFields.Geolocation__Latitude__s')` - undefined

`component.set('v.objectFields.Source_Percentage__c', 23)` - undefined

`component.get('v.objectFields.Source_Percentage__c')` - 23

`component.set("v.objectFields.Name", 'TEST/123')` - undefined

`component.get("v.objectFields.Name")` - TEST/123

Comment: I would assume the permissions for the contextual user have changed.

Comment: I thought it might be that but I am testing it using System Administrator and have tried manually editing those fields myself and it's fine.

Comment: Just remember that even Sys Admin needs to have permissions for fields - this is often automatically added, but not always. That said, your second part that it works through the standard UI makes this unlikely the issue.

Comment: Found the issue! The field has to be on the page layout

Answer (score 1):

When using `force:recordData`, you can only update fields that are on the record's page layout (or compact layout if `layoutType` is `COMPACT`).

Adding the field to the page layout will solve this issue.

(The reason we have recently had this issue is because we started using  Dynamic Forms)

Comment: Yeah, so many things still need the page layout even when you have dynamic forms... some serious gaps to be filled...